# Pyspark - Saving & using previously calculated values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset of thousands of files and I read / treat them with **PySpark**.

First, I've created functions like the following one to treat the whole dataset and this is working great.

```
def get_volume_spark(data):
    days = lambda i: i * 86400 # This is 60sec*60min*24h 

    partition = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy(F.col("date").cast("long")).rangeBetween(days(-31), days(0))

    data = data.withColumn("monthly_volume", F.count(F.col("op_id")).over(partition))\
                .filter(F.col("monthly_volume") >= COUNT_THRESHOLD)

    return data
```

Every day I got new files arriving and I want to **treat new files ONLY** and append data the the first created file instead of treating the whole dataset again with more data every day because it would be too long and operations has been already made.

The other thing is, here I split by month for example (I calculate the count per month), but no one can assure that I will have a whole month (and certainly not) in the new files. So I want to keep a counter or something to resume where I were.

I wanted to know if there's some way to do that or this is not possible at all.

Comment: If you split this into two step it will be easier. First, when you get file load file and partition it by date. Then you can compute the metrics. Other approach will be write your previously computed metrics into folder say current and backup/date=YYYYMMDD and then  when you get new file use current data from backup to compute next data and write into current and backup/date=YYYYMMDD.

Comment: Yeah though about something like that but did not know if that were the best option